# Kubernetes kubectl command got error

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, credentials, kubectl, rancher

Using Rancher master installed K8S cluster on CentOS 7.(3 hosts)
When run `kubectl version` at master host, got error:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.4", GitCommit:"9befc2b8928a9426501d3bf62f72849d5cbcd5a3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-20T05:28:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

I copied kube config file from Rancher dashboard to local(edited secret information):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    api-version: v1
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: "https://192.168.0.1:8080/r/projects/1a7/kubernetes"
  name: "k8s"
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: "k8s"
    user: "k8s"
  name: "k8s"
current-context: "k8s"
users:
- name: "k8s"
  user:
    username: "111222333444AAABBBCCC"
    password: "111222333444AAABBBCCC111222333444AAABBBCCC"
```

Why?

Comment: for sanity, does `kubectl config view` emit the yaml you quoted (that is: does `kubectl` see the config file like you expect)?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel That was due to the `etcd`. I removed it from all the k8s hosts. It works.